# Twin Slider control .net

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, slider

Has anyone seen a good twin slider control for .Net (Win forms or WPF).

I'm looking for something that will allow me to select a range from within a set so the first slider would be the start of the range and the second would be the end.

I remember seeing a Swing double slider but it was 6 years ago and I can't for the life of me remember who made it. It was open source though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Devexpress have a good one:

The RangeTrackBarControl control extends the functionality provided by the TrackBarControl enabling end-users to select a range of values. Two sliders can be used to set the minimum and maximum values:

[alt text http://www.devexpress.com/Help/XtraEditors/img/RangeTrackBarControl.png](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/XtraEditors/img/RangeTrackBarControl.png)

you can get them free from:

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/WebRegistration/

hope this helps!

Comment: DevExpress is NOT free!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I cannot comment on the previous answer. DevExpress does not appear to offer any free controls any more; only a free 30-day trial.